# How to loop over the json data and modify the accessor name?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a json data as {name: "Misha", name:"Sam"....} and I am trying to change the name to nickname so it will be {nickname: "Misha"...}
Tried different things but ended up changing the value but not the accessor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can construct a new object

```js
let obj = { name: "Misha" };
obj = { nickname: obj.name };

console.log(obj);
```

or reassign the property.

```js
let obj = { name: "Misha" };
obj.nickname = obj.name;
delete obj.name;

console.log(obj);
```